# Nomenclatura de alcanos Python 2.7

Tags: python

Necesito programar la siguiente situación en Python 2.7...

- **ENTRADA**: Archivo de texto (.txt) con la fórmula de un alcano.
- **SALIDA**: Número del carbono donde se encuentra acoplada una estructura a la cadena más larga junto a dicha estructura separado por "-". Ejemplo: 1-CH3, 2-CH2-CH3.

  ```
                 CH3       CH3            #Ejemplo del contenido del
                   |         |            #archivo de texto
      CH3-CH2-CH2-CH-CH-CH2-CH-CH2-CH3    # Nombre de la molécula:
                      |                   #5-butil-3,6-dimetilnonano
                     CH2-CH2-CH2-CH3
  ```

Lo que busco es algo más simple que el nombre. Necesito que el programa me indique el número del carbono en el cual está unida una estructura a la cadena más larga, por ejemplo el nombre de la molécula dice `5-butil`, lo que busco programar es obtener un resultado semejante, pero en este caso para mi programa sería `5-CH2-CH2-CH2-CH3`. He intentado, pero no logro resultados cercanos. Dejo un ejemplo de lo que llevo, es poco y quizás no sirva mucho, pero no sé cómo abordar el problema.

```
archivo = open("rama.txt","r") #Ramas es el nombre del archivo con el mismo contenido
lineas = archivo.readlines() #Guardo las líneas del archivo en listas
cad = lineas[len(lineas)/2]  #Almaceno la cadena más larga en la variable cad
cad2 = cad                   #Variable auxiliar para no modificar la original
cad2 = cad2.split("-")       #Creo una lista de la cadena más larga separando elementos por el caracter "-"
i = 1
while i < len(cad2):           #Itero sobre la cadena larga para reemplazar los CH por números (como string)
     if cad2[i] == "CH":
          cad2[i] = str(i + 1)
     i += 1
print cad2
```

Salida:

```
['CH3', 'CH2', 'CH2', '4', '5', 'CH2', '7', 'CH2', 'CH3\n']
```

No es el orden que debería tener ya que el 7 debería ser un 3 y el 4 un 6, pero no se me ha ocurrido cómo corregirlo.

PD : Desconozco el tema de "grafos".

Comment: Tamos, debes editar tu pregunta siguiendo la guía [mcve]. De lo contrario podría ser cerrada.

Comment: Además estaria bién que aclarases cual es la salida esperada del programa, ¿que deberia imprimir con ese ejemplo que das? Si no me confundo la cadena más larga en este caso es de 9 carbonos. Una solución para estos casos es implementar un grafo y trabajar sobre el.

Comment: cual es la entrada: un texto, una imagen??

Comment: la entrada es el archivo de texto con esa formula

Comment: Tamos pero repito ¿Cual es la salida esperada para ese caso por ejemplo? Aclara que debe hacer el programa exactamente porque yo al menos no lo entiendo ¿debe encontrar la cadena de carbosnos más larga? Si deseas que se reabra la pregunta deberias añadir el código que has intentado (da igual que este mal, para eso estamos aquí) y explicar mejor que debe hacer el programa.

Comment: la salida es la posición o mejor dicho el número del carbono donde tiene unida una estructura, no sé si me explico bien, y se indica la estructura que esta unida, por ejemplo: 1-CH3.

Comment: Soy nuevo por eso no entiendo bien como hacer un post, lo siento, trataré de re formular la pregunta adecuadamente para que quede más claro. Gracias

Comment: No te preocupes, solo intenta explicarla como si no supieramos nada de química. Una cosa, sigo sin pillar lo de 'el número del carbono donde tiene unida una estructura', a ver si no recuerdo mal (mi quimica queda lejana) los carbonos que tienen cadenas (radicales) en este ejemplo son el carbono 3(CH3), el 5 (CH2-CH2-CH2-CH3) y el 6(CH3) por lo que no pillo de donde viene lo de 1-CH3.

Comment: es un ejemplo de como debe ser el resultado esperado solamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que según las reglas de nomenclatura de los alcanos se empieza a numerar por el extremo que tiene un radical más cercano.

Tal y como tienes tu código siempre empieza a numerar de izquierda a derecha cuando en el ejemplo se debería empezar a numerar de derecha a izquierda.

Para solucionarlo simplemente tienes que ver por que lado de la lista te encuentras antes con un `CH`, si es por el final simplemente tendrias que invertir la lista, hacer lo mismo que haces y luego volverla a invertir.

El código podría quedar asi:

```
def identidicar_radicales(cadena):
    for i, atomo in enumerate(cadena):
        if cadena[i] == "CH":
             cadena[i] = str(i + 1)
    return cadena


archivo = open("molecula.txt","r")
lineas = archivo.readlines()
archivo.close()

cad = lineas[len(lineas)//2].rstrip('\n')
cad2 = cad.split("-")
cad2_invertida = cad2[::-1]

if cad2.index('CH') > cad2_invertida.index('CH'):
    cad2 = identidicar_radicales(cad2_invertida)[::-1]

else:
    cad2 = identidicar_radicales(cad2)

print cad2
```

Tu ciclo `while` lo pasado a un `for` con `enumerate()` que hace inecesaria la variable `i` ya que retorna en una tupla cada elemnto con su indice.

Usando tu ejemplo para crear un txt, obtenemos la siguiente salida:

```
['CH3', 'CH2', 'CH2', '6', '5', 'CH2', '3', 'CH2', 'CH3']
```

**Actualización:**

Dado que hay otras preguntas similares que se han marcado como duplicado de esta y que preguntan por como identificar la cadena más larga voy a exponer una posible forma de realizarlo implementando un `grafo` para representar la molécula:

- Leemos los datos del `txt` y creamos un `grafo` (un árbol) en el que cada carbono es un `nodo` o `vértice` y cada enlace una `arista`. Para ello se suelen usar `diccionarios` y representar el grafo como **listas de adyacencias**. Como los nodos tienen que tener nombres distintos renombramos cada carbono, por ejemplo numerándolos por orden de aparición en el `txt`. Con un diccionario independiente podemos ir guardando el carbono asociado a cada número. Para parsear el `txt` es múy útil el uso de expresiones regulares (ver módulo `re` de Python).

  Para el ejemplo dado aquí quedaria un grafo como el siguiente:

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

  El grafo quedaría representado  como un diccionario de la siguiente forma:

  ```
  {1: {6}, 2: {9}, 3: {4}, 4: {3, 5}, 5: {4, 6}, 6: {1, 5, 7}, 7: {8, 12, 6}, 8: {9, 7}, 9: {8, 2, 10}, 10: {9, 11}, 11: {10}, 12: {13, 7}, 13: {12, 14}, 14: {13, 15}, 15: {14}}
  ```

  Donde cada `key` es el nombre de un nodo y tiene como `valor` un `set` con los nodos adyacentes (con los que tiene enlaces).

  El diccionario con las traducciones (para luego reconstruir la molécula o sus cadenas) podria quedar:

  ```
  {1:'CH3', 2:'CH3', 3:'CH3', 4:'CH2', 5:'CH2', 6:'CH', 7:'CH', 8:'CH', 9:'CH', 10:'CH2', 11'CH3':, 12:'CH2', 13:'CH2', 14:'CH2', 15:'CH3'}
  ```
- Una vez que tenemos el grafo encontrar la cadena o cadenas más largas se reduce a encontrar los caminos más largos entre las **hojas** del árbol, es decir, buscamos los caminos entre los **nodos que solo tienen una arista**.

  En este caso los caminos más largos tienen 9 carbonos y son los siguientes:

  ```
  [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
  [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15]
  [11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15]
  ```

  Para obtener el camino entre dos nodos podemos usar la [**búsqueda en anchura (algoritmo BFS)**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BAsqueda_en_anchura) que es fácil de implementar.
- Ahora ya queda seguir trabajando con las facilidades que nos da el grafo con el resto de reglas de la nomenclatura de alcanos para al final poder obtener salidas con el nombre de la molécula o su representación gráfica correcta.

Dado que esto suele ser objeto de tareas escolares mi objetivo era solo dar una posible idea sin proporcionr el código ya que no entra dentro de la filosofía de Stack Overflow proporcionar respuestas completas a tareas escolares. Se puede implementar usando POO en unas 80 lineas perfectamente y una vez obtenido el grafo manejar la molécula es realmente sencillo. La misma idea se puede extender a otro tipo de moléculas con enlaces dobles, anillos, etc.